# Why do I get a sender rejected from postfix when sending from phpmailer?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, postfix-mta

When I run the following PHP code I get an error.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER; // debug
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $uname;
$mail->Password = $pw;
$mail->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;
$mail->setFrom('no-reply@example.com', 'website registration');
$mail->addAddress($cleaned_email);
$mail->Subject = 'Please verify your account';
$msg = '[registration text...]'
$msg = wordwrap($msg, 70);
$mail->Body = $msg;
                        
if (!$mail->send()) {
  echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit();
} else {
  [... add user to db, etc...]
}
```

The mail appears to be sent. No error is generated by PHPMailer and the database code is run.

Here is the error generated in mail.log.

`Aug 22 11:47:06 server postfix/smtp[8339]: 079AB1F909: to=<outsider-at-anydomain.com>, relay=mail.brighthouse.com[47.43.26.56]:25, delay=5.7, delays=0.06/0.02/0.31/5.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <user-at-example.com> sender rejected. Please see understanding-email-error-codes for more information.)`

I have tried changing the send from address to my user that I am authenticating with in the PHP code.

I have tried adding a smtpd_sender_login_maps paramter with a matching hash table to my postfix config to map the no-reply address to my user that I authenticate with, but it ignores it as an unused parameter.

Postfix config:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
#smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = server
mydomain = example.com
virtual_alias_domains = example2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, server, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = mail.brighthouse.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
notify_classes = resource, software, 2bounce
home_mailbox = Maildir/
#mailbox_command =
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination
        reject_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
        check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smptd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHPMailer. Your local mail server accepts the message, but onward delivery fails. This will be because of the addresses you’ve chosen; some hosts are much pickier than others. You could test more directly by sending to the target host from PHPMailer, bypassing your local server, at least until you figure Out what’s going on.

Comment: Does this mean the relay server (my ISP's in this case) is sending the sender rejected error? If so why would emails from a mail client (outlook, ios) be accepted and delivered but fail when coming from php, specifically phpmailer. The native mail() function in php also returns the same error. How would I go about running the test you suggest? Would bypassing my local server be a viable production option?

Comment: Because they are coming from different places. Yes, the relay server is sending the rejection. Both PHPMailer and mail() are using the same sending server. In short, the problem is your addressing, not PHPMailer, as I said.

Comment: could you expand on what you mean by my addressing? if i enter the same address as the from that i use with my outlook and ios clients, i get the exact same message in the log file, except the mail is accepted by the relay, not rejected. What is php doing differently?

Comment: Check the envelope sender in each case. It may help to compare the messages after they’re received by your relay, but before they are sent on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My issue has nothing to do with PHP Mailer. The php code I posted works. My issue is with my email server setup. I have posted a more server related question on Super User here: https://superuser.com/questions/1580944/soho-postfix-dovecot-configuration-for-small-web-app-and-user-base

Thank you all for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the "from" address is incorrect:

> $mail->setFrom('no-reply at example dot com', 'website registration');

you need to use a valid email address, such as:

```
$mail->setFrom('no-reply@example.com', 'website registration');
```

Comment: The syntax rules for email addresses are quite a lot to reference here, but you can look for example here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax

Comment: Apologies, I have formatted the email address correctly. Stack Overflow kept complaining that my post was spam and I was trying to figure out what it was. Some searching suggested it could be links and email addresses in the text.

Comment: > $mail->Username = uname;
$mail->Password = pw;

Is that just for the purposes of not posting your auth publicly? Because those are not valid PHP variables...